# Mosquitto failed to start on macOS: "Service exited with abnormal code: 3"

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to start an MQTT broker with websocket on my macOS. So I changed just the following two lines on the conf file `/usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`:

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

And I try to run it using `brew services start mosquitto -d`, but it doesn't work. I checked using `netstat -nat | grep 9001`, but there is no result, and on the logs file `/var/log/system.log` I can see the following error:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto[46643]): Service exited with abnormal code: 3
```

If I don't make the changes on the conf file that I said, I can run the broker, but without websocket:

```
> netstat -nat | grep 1883
tcp6       0      0  ::1.1883               *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.1883         *.*                    LISTEN
```

How can I solve that?

---

When I try running without homebrew:

```
> /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf 
1611655055: mosquitto version 2.0.5 starting
1611655055: Config loaded from /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1611655055: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1611655055: Error: Unable to start any listening sockets, exiting.
```

My whole conf: https://pastebin.com/hh4fND7D

Comment: Do you have libwebsockets install? Also rather than running it as a service what happens if you run it from the command line `mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: @hardillb I receive the error `Error: Unable to start any listening sockets, exiting` - I updated the question with the result, to be easier to read the full logs.

Comment: And you've checked there is nothing already listening on port 9001?

Comment: @hardillb Yeah. I checked using the command `netstat -nat | grep 9001`

Comment: Have you enabled the built-in firewall on your mac?

Comment: Is that whole `mosquitto.conf`? if not please edit the question to include the whole config file for when it fails.

Comment: @hardillb Done. https://pastebin.com/hh4fND7D

Comment: @kometen Yeah, but I can create a process that listen the port 9001

Comment: The firewall may not apply to localhost. But either way usually allows outgoing connections, but prevents incoming, unless permitted by a rule.

Comment: @kometen I disabled the firewall, but I'm still having the same error

Comment: Your config file loads fine on my linux macine with mosquitto 2.0.5 so this has to be something Mac/Brew specific.